# Preview previous revision without restoring it

Tags: revisions

I need to restore the website to an old revision but not sure which one. How do I preview old revisions without restoring until I am sure it is the right one?

Comment: Are you talking about a page revision inside WordPress or about older versions of your entire website that you are restoring from your hosting provider's back end?

Comment: If you mean restoring one post (or page or cpt), you can't preview revisions. Copy your database onto a staging/dev site and revert to an old revision - then you can preview that revision and see if it's what you're looking for. Or, if you don't want to copy everything to a staging/dev site, you'll have to work with the WP Revision screen which shows things in more of a HTML view very much unlike Preview.